# how to read data separated by ' ' but that has decimal numbers with comma

Tags: octave

I need to read and modify a .txt file with thousands of lines. This file represents the reading of a digital signal. Each line has the following format:

```
8867.16787 : 1
```

There are two numbers separated by `" space : space "`:

- The first number is a decimal number separated by '.'
- The second number is a integer number that can be 0 or 1.

The meaning is: The first number is a kind of time measure and the second is the bit read.

Considering a matrix of four lines as an example:

```
1532.25071 : 0
1532.26311 : 0
1532.27511 : 0
1532.28751 : 1
```

I would like a matrix of two columns, where the first column would be:

```
1532.25071
1532.26311
1532.27511
1532.28751
```

and the second:

```
0
0
0
1
```

I tried the following code:

```
fid = fopen('fileName');
A = textscan(fid,'%s %c %c');
fclose(fid);
```

But, when I do this I have a Matrix of dimension 1x3.

Does someone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following and worked fine:

```
fileX = 'fileName';
delimitador = ' : ';
A = importdata(fileX );
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to just use other format specifiers for [`textscan`](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Simple-File-I_002fO.html#index-textscan), then format the output from a cell array into a matrix of values. Try this:

```
fid = fopen('fileName');
A = textscan(fid, '%f : %f');  % Read both as double values
fclose(fid);
A = [A{:}];  % Horizontally concatenate into an N-by-2 double matrix
```

Comment: No, it did not work. when I do this the A matrix become a matrix of dimension 1x2. the element A(1,1) became a list of all floating numbers of the file.

Comment: just add the number of element to read in the call to textscan: `A = textscan(fid,'%f : %d',Inf);`